# identity for the second fundamental form for cones

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following:

---

Let $C$ be a $n$ dimensional minimal cone in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with vertex at $0$ with second fundamental form $h_{ij} = h_{ji}$. (Minimal implies $\sum_i h_{ii} = 0$)

Also, let $h_{ijk}$ be the components of the one-form definied by $$\sum_k h_{ijk} \omega_k = \mathrm d h_{ij} - \sum_k h_{ik} \, \omega_{kj} - \sum_k h_{jk} \, \omega_{ki},$$
where all sums are from $1$ to $n$, $\{\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n\}$ are the dual frames to $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ and $\{\omega_{ij}\}_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ are the connection one-forms.

---

> Choose a frame $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ such that $h_{ij}$ is diagonal and $e_n$ is in radial direction (ie. $e_n = x/|x|$).
>
> Then we have $h_{ij} = h_{nn} = 0$, $i \neq j$ and $h_{ijn} = - |x|^{-1} \, h_{ij}$, $i,j = 1,\cdots,n$

Now I understand that $h_{nn} = 0$ since in the radial direction, the cone just looks like a straight line.

**My Question:** How do I see the second identity? $$h_{ijn} = - |x|^{-1} \, h_{ij}, \quad i,j = 1,\cdots,n$$

---

**EDIT** So my idea was to look at this 
\begin{align}
h_{ijn} & = (\mathrm d h_{ij})(e_n) - \sum_k h_{ik} \, \omega_{kj}(e_n) - \sum_k h_{jk} \, \omega_{ki}(e_n) \\
% & = \partial_n h_{ii} \, \delta_{ij} - \Gamma^i_{nj} \, h_{ii} - \Gamma^j_{ni} \, h_{jj}
\end{align}

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your definition of "minimal cone" ?

Comment: as i understand very basic; just a union of rays starting at 0 AND $\sum_i h_{ii} = 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a cone is radially self-similar, and curvature (as measured by the second fundamental form) scales like inverse length, its curvatures at $x$ and $\lambda x$ (for any $\lambda > 0$) will be related by $$h_{ij}(\lambda x) = \lambda^{-1} h_{ij}(x)$$ if we work in a frame that is parallel in the radial direction. That is, in this frame, the components of the second fundamental form are positively homogeneous of degree $-1$.

In terms of connection coefficients, this extra condition on the frame translates to $\omega_{ijn}=0;$ so we have the simple formula $h_{ijn} = \partial_n h_{ij}.$ By [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity), we have the derivative formula $$x^k \partial_k h_{ij} = |x| h_{ijn}= -h_{ij},$$ which can be rearranged to give $h_{ijn} = -|x|^{-1} h_{ij}$ as desired.

Finally, to relax the extra condition on the frame I added, note that your $h_{ijn}$ is really the covariant derivative $\nabla_n h_{ij}$ written in terms of moving frames; so we have shown the coordinate-independent equation $\nabla_X h = -|x|^{-1} h$ for $X$ the radial unit vector field, and thus $h_{ijn} = \nabla_n h_{ij} = -|x|^{-1} h_{ij}$ whenever $e_n =X$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! one question: i suppose, by $\omega_{ijn}$ you mean the connection coefficients (ie. Christoffel symobols wrt to the frame; $\omega_{ijn} = \omega_{ij}(e_n) = \mathbf \Gamma_{ijn}$). How do you conclude that $\omega_{ijn} = 0$?

Comment: @cesareborgia: Yes. By definition we have $\omega_{ijn}e_i = \nabla_{e_n} e_j$ (maybe with $i,j$ swapped depending on your convention), so this vanishing is exactly the condition that the frame is parallel in the radial/$e_n$ direction.